# Exception in conversion of hidden field value to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am facing an issue regarding type conversion. a value is coming from database store procedure. And I am storing that value in this hidden field like this.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hfScheduleDate" runat="server"  value='<%#Eval("ScheduleDate") %>' />
```

and try to convert it in like this way.

```
DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(hfScheduleDate.Value);
```

now it is giving an exception.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Please provide an example of a string you are trying to convert to datetime

Comment: DateTime scheduledate= Convert.ToDateTime(hfScheduleDate.Value)

Comment: I've seen it in your question. Show me the value of 'hfScheduleDate.Value'

Comment: '2015/05/07 18:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit 'dangerous' doing it like this. There're a few options:

1. Read it directly from the database, without converting it to a string first
2. Use DateTime.ParseExact. See [MSDN DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details and examples.
3. Use Convert.ToDateTime with a CultureInfo object. See this [MSDN How To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide CultureInfo to convertion method like this

```
 string Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/09", 
                         new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd");
                         //Results 2009-Jan-02
 string Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/09", 
                         new CultureInfo("ru-RU")).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd");
                         //Results 2009-Feb-01
 string Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/09", 
                         new CultureInfo("ja-JP")).ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd");
                         //Results 2001-Feb-09
```

There are many other formats you can search for.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime` method uses `DateTime.Parse` method with your `CurrentCulture` settings *by default*.

That means (*I assume your 05 is your month part*), your `CurrentCulture` does not have `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).<sup>1</sup>

As an alternative, you can use [custom date and time formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supply exact format with culture that has `/` as a `DateSeparator` and `:` as a `TimeSeparator` like `InvariantCulture` (if your current culture does not have these)

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(hfScheduleDate.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

1: <sub>Since [`/` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) is a date separator in custom date and time formatting, it will be use your `CurrentCulture`'s `DateSeparator` by default.</sub>